# how to drive a 1080p monitor from a lenovo thinkpad T60?

Tags: display, hdmi, lenovo

Just installed Ubuntu 11.10 on the thinkpad. It is in its base that has a displayport output which I route through an adaptor through to the HDMI input of my 1080p TV/monitor.

Comment: Re-installing Ubuntu with the laptop in its dock and connected to the monitor sorted this. It correctly found the Sony monitor and has up to 1080p settings available for it now.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It would be interesting to know, if cold-booting in its dock would have solved the problem too. And: if the problem occurs again, if cold-bootet undocked and plugged in as you tried at first.
In my experience, reinstalling ubuntu does not solve driver-problems, only config-errors...